# UV mapping for exporting blender textures to unity

Tags: uv, export, unity

I am using UV mapping for exporting textures to unity. Firstly i map the object with smart uv mapping and then bake it. After that I save the image as png;  add it into material as texture of object in unity.

With that process should I save and export blender file again after mapping objects or can i just use texture files directly? How unity understand UV maps if I just add textures as png files? I am assuming composite nodes are not exported with that method. Are there any method for exporting composite nodes?

And are there any easier method?

Comment: The image texture files (.png etc.) don't contain any mapping information on their own. I suppose it *might* be possible to bake the mapping to an image if both programs make some assumptions about the space such a mapping is represented in, but I've never heard of things being done that way. Depending on exactly how you are importing/exporting, you might be better off adding the texture to the object in blender, then exporting object, texture, and UV map from blender all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export your model again once you UV mapped it, because unity will not be able to get the UV data as your model don't have them.